# Shift of -1 in MatLab after Convolution

Tags: matlab, convolution

I have noticed a shift of -1 when doing convolution in MatLab (R2011b) using the conv function and I don't understand why. I am using the 'same' option to the convolution function because my signal and the function I am convolving with are the same N pixels in length and I want my result to also be N pixels.

This shift only happens when I have my value of N as even number.

I wrote this short script to illustrate the problem. It convolves a rectangle pulse with an impulse response, so I dont expect any shift in my result.

```
%% Set up rectangle pulse

N = 21;

signal = zeros(N, 1);

% Designate some pixels in the signal as 1's to make rectangle pulse

signal(9:11) = 1;

%% Set up impulse for convolution

impulse = zeros(N, 1);

impulse(round(N/2)) = 1;

%% Convolution

convolutionResult = conv(signal, impulse, 'same');

%% Plot Results - not shown
```

When N is odd the result looks OK, i.e. the rectangle pulse has values of 1 at pixels 9, 10 and 11, as expected, the same as before convolution.

[image: N is odd]

But if N is odd, then the rectangle pulse has values of 1 at pixels 8, 9 and 10, so a shift of -1 which I don't get. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Does anybody understand why this happens?

Comment: OK I know why, after writing it out I noticed that the position of the '1' value in my impulse is obviously the reason. Not to worry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `w = conv(u,v,'same');`, It says,

> **same** : Returns the central part of the convolution of the same size as u.

when `N` is `even` and `same` for both signals the result of convolution has `2N - 1` samples, which is `odd`, so when trying to select the center of that with an `even` length, `N`, the expression `central part` looses its meaning.

If time axis is important for you, don't use `same` option.

Comment: Thanks Kamtal, I see my mistake and misunderstanding now. I'll make yours as correct when it lets me. Is 'same' significantly slower than not specifying an option?

Comment: @DukeOfMarmalade, I suppose It has the advantage of low memory consumption but takes more time to delete extra parts.